# Dowloading Files One at a time in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download one file at a time.  But when I add my value2 into the await Task.Delay(value2); It still downloads both files at the same instead of one at a time.  Mind you that I will be putting checkboxes to the ones that I want to download and there are going to be about 20 to 50 downloads to which I would be able to choose which to download.  But the main thing is how to download one at a time instead of all at the same time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace DownloadFileCSharp8
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Stopwatch workerTimeElaspsed;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnGetDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = label5.Text;
        int value2;
        //value2 = value2 + 5;

        int.TryParse(text, out value2);



        InitiateDownload("http://stie.text1.txt", @"E:\Files\text1.txt", wc_DownloadFileCompleted, "text1.txt");


        await Task.Delay(value2);

        InitiateDownload("http://site.text.docx", @"E:\Files\text2.docx", wc_DownloadFileCompleted, "text2.docx");
    }

     void InitiateDownload(string RemoteAddress, string LocalFile, AsyncCompletedEventHandler CompleteCallBack, object userToken)
    {


        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadTimer);       
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(RemoteAddress), LocalFile, userToken);



        workerTimeElaspsed = new Stopwatch();
        workerTimeElaspsed.Start();


    }

     private void DownloadTimer(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
     {


         progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

         if (e.ProgressPercentage > 0)
         {
             double totalTime = (100d / (double)e.ProgressPercentage) * workerTimeElaspsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
             double remaining = totalTime - workerTimeElaspsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
             label5.Text = Math.Round(remaining).ToString();

         }


     }

    void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            lblInfo1.Visible = true;
            lblInfo1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInfo1.Text = "Error Downloading ";

            //throw e.Error;
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            lblInfo1.Visible = true;
            lblInfo1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInfo1.Text = "Download Cancelled " + e.UserState + e.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            lblInfo1.Visible = true;
            lblInfo1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblInfo1.Text = e.UserState + " Download Complete!! ";
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
}
```

Comment: @AppDeveloper He *wants* them to be sequential, rather than parallel.  That post is asking how to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You call `InitiateDownload` to start the download, then wait for a fixed period of time (which appears to be very short), then you call `InitiateDownload` again to start another download *regardless of whether or not the first download has finished.

What you want to do is re-write `InitiateDownload` so that it returns a `Task` that indicates when the download is complete.  You can then `await` that task and start the next download when it is done.

The easiest way to do that is to simply use the `DownloadDataTaskAsync` method instead of `DownloadFileAsync`.

Comment: when I tried DownloadDataTaskAsync I am not able to insert [link](new Uri(RemoteAddress), LocalFile, userToken)].  I need it to download to a folder kind of like I have it.  Still trying to figure out async & await and tasks.  Is there an easier way or do I have to change somethings around.

Comment: @user3329960 Rather than passing a local file, the task itself will provides you the bytes.  You can write them to a file when the task has completed if you want.  There is no real need to pass in the user token, as you'll still have access to it after you `await` the task.  This approach will be *much* easier and simpler than what you have now.  It'd almost be worth starting from scratch, because most of what you've already done is just unnecessary.

Comment: Will I still use DownloadFileCompleted or DownloadDataCompleted...

Comment: @user3329960 No, you need not use either.  Simply do whatever you would have done when the task was completed after you `await` the task.  The result of the task has all of the information needed to do what you were doing in those methods.

Comment: I keep making my code worse is there somewhere that you point me to because I tried searching the web but nothing similar to what I am trying to do or maybe give a hint of how it should be done.  Please help...

Comment: @user3329960 You call `DownloadDataTaskAsync`, you `await` it, and then you use the result to do your processing on the data.  Then repeat for the second file you're interested in.

Comment: I do this wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(RemoteAddress), LocalFile, userToken); but it gives an error type.

Comment: @user3329960 You can look at the documentation of the method to see what parameters it expects.  YOu need to match your parameters to what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your DownloadFileCompleted event to trigger the next InitiateDownload if you want them to happen serially.